# Is there any way to get Varnish switch from Connection: Keep-Alive to Close?

Tags: caching, http-headers, connection, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have Varnish 6 installed on Ubuntu in front of Apache2.4 as backend.

I have tried to set it in sub `vcl_pipe`,  `vcl_backend_response`:

```
set bereq.http.Connection = "close";
```

I've tried to set  it in `vcl_recv` as:

```
req.http.Connection = "close";
```

I've tried to set it in `vcl_deliver` :

```
set resp.http.Connection = "Close";
```

None of it helped at all. Even though when I use varnishlog, I can see that the repose connection header was set to "Close, in fact when I get it in browser - the Connection is still set as "Keep-alive".

Is there any possible way to manipulate connection response header in Varnish?
P.S As a matter of fact - I do change the connection response header to "Close" in my back end framework, but Varnish wouldn't pass it through to the client, so I started to dig deeper and tried to change that in Varnish config, but it does not work, no matter what. The connection would always be "Keep-alive".

Maybe I should try another Varnish version (4 or 5?).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you remember to restart Varnish?

Comment: In what stage do you want to manipulate the Connection header? Between the client and varnish? Or between varnish and your backend(s)?

Answer (score 1):

> I can see that the repose connection header was set to "Close, in fact when I get it in browser - the Connection is still set as "Keep-alive".

How? If the browser gets "Close", then it's a close. What makes you think it's a keep-alive?

To answer your questions(s):

- by default, varnish nukes the connection header before entering `vcl_pipe`, so the connection is closed. This is to avoid giving the client unfettered access to the backend.
- if you want to close the connection to the client, unset `req.http.connection`, or set it to "close" in `vcl_recv`, varnish will respect that and will close the connection.
- if you want to close the connection on the backend side, `req.http.connection`, or set it to "close" in `vcl_backend_fetch`, varnish will respect that and will close the connection.

Comment: An example to "return 444" like nginx do: `sub vcl_recv { if (...) { unset req.http.connection; return (pipe); } }`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sub vcl_pipe {
set bereq.http.Connection = "close";
}
```

See https://www.google.nl/amp/s/info.varnish-software.com/blog/using-pipe-varnish